# How to pass argument to Java Process?

Tags: java

I have a Java application that creates and runs a process (x.exe). When process x is executed, it prompts the user to enter a password. How to pass this password to the user?

I tried to use the `OutputStream` of the process and wrote the password to the stream but still the process didn't run.

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("x.exe");
p.getOutputStream()//.use to pass the arguments
```

Comment: You'll need to flesh out this question a bit more before it becomes on-topic for StackOverflow. "no result achieved" is not an appropriate description of what went wrong - how are we supposed to know what happened on your computer? And what/how did you pass "the arguments"? Show *all* the relevant code.

Comment: You'll need to pass an appropriate line terminator if the process is trying to read a line, and if the process is specifically reading from the console you can't write to that at all. You need to post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush the stream, and also, it maybe expects a CR at the end of the password to simulate the ENTER key the user types at the end of the password. This works for me in Linux:

```
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec("myTestingExe");
    p.getOutputStream().write("myPassword\n".getBytes()); // notice the `\n`
    p.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Some caveats:

- This works in Linux with '\n' at the end, maybe in Windows you would need \r instead (honestly I'm not sure of how Windows handles the "ENTER" key in the input)
- I'm using `"myPassword\n".getBytes()` but a more complete value would be `new String("myPassword".getBytes(), Charset.forName("MyCharsetName"));` (where "MyCharsetName" is a supported encoding) if you are using an encoding like "UTF-8".

Answer (score 2):

As already was pointed out you can consider to use an [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)-like library for interacting between your Java program and a spawn OS process. Basically, you would need to wait until the password prompt gets available in the process input stream and then write the password terminated by the end-of-line to the process output stream.

If you decide to go with a third party library approach I'd recommend you to give a try my own modern alternative to [expect4j](https://code.google.com/p/expect4j/) and others. It is called [ExpectIt](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt) has no dependencies and is Apache licensed.

Here is a possible example with the use of the expect library:

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");
    Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
            .withInputs(process.getInputStream())
            .withOutput(process.getOutputStream())
            .withErrorOnTimeout(true)
            .build();
    expect.expect(contains("Password:"));
    expect.sendLine("secret");
    expect.close();
```

Note: the `contains` method is statically imported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try library like [expect4j](https://code.google.com/p/expect4j/) to interact with the external process

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.